# sizeof operator with pointers

Tags: c, pointers

```
#include<stdio.h>

void main()
{
   int a[2][3][4];

   printf("%d",sizeof(*a));  // Output 24.
}
```

My doubt is array 'a' is of type int (*)[3][4]. Now after de-referencing( * a), it will become int ( * )[4]. So the size should be 4*2=8 as the pointer points to array of 4 integers. But the output is 4*3*2=24.

Can someone please tell where am I going wrong?

Comment: `array 'a' is of type int (*)[3][4].`..umm..no?

Comment: On dereferencing `a` you will get the type `int[3][4]`, do not decay to pointer needlessly.

Comment: arrays are not pointers and vice-versa.

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya, How to decide when to decay it to int[3][4] and int (*)[4].

Comment: @RajeshR check the answer I have posted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some major confusions regarding types here -

Firstly your statement - `a` is of type `int (*)[3][4]`, No!

`a` is declared with type `int[2][3][4]` and it stays that unless it is decayed to a pointer say while passing to a function.

Now when you write `*a`, you dereference it once, giving you the type - `int[3][4]`. Since you say that your `int` is of size 2 bytes, you get `2 * 3 * 4 = 24` bytes.

As suggested by @FelixPalmen, an identifier of type array will always decay to a pointer to it's first element **except** when it is an operand to `sizeof`, `_Alignof`  or `&`. Since you have used `sizeof` here , it wont.

On the other hand if a was declared as `int (*(*a))[4];` what you are saying would have been correct and `*a` would have the size as `sizeof(pointer)` which could be anything depending on your system.

Comment: What in case of `sizeof(**a)` ? Here `int (*)[3][4]` has to be decayed to `int (*)[4]` right:? Then why don't we do the same for `sizeof(*a)` ?

Comment: @RajeshR no, even in that case it isn't decayed. `a` is `int[2][3][4]`, `*a` is `int[3][4]`, `**a` is `int[4]` and `***a` is `int`.

Comment: But the way we get `int[4]` from `**a` is, `*a=int (*)[4]` and now `**a is int[4]` right?

Comment: @RajeshR no, dereferencing an array __also__ gives the element type, not just pointer. Think of the `*`operator as `[0]` after the variable. What will be the type of `a[0]`? `int[3][4]` right?

Comment: If `a` was declared as `int (*(*a))[4];` what you are saying would have been correct. And in that case the size would have been `sizeof(pointer)`.

Comment: But when we pass an array int a[2][3][4] to printf function it automatically decays it to its equivalent int (*)[3][4].

Comment: @RajeshR yes, in my answer I have provided some scenarios where the decay is performed. One among them is passing to any function(not just printf).

Comment: "*only when explicitly done by say casting, assigning to the corresponding pointer type or passing to (or returning from) a function.*" <- not exactly. The identifier of an array will *always* evaluate as a pointer to the first element *except* when it is the operand of `sizeof`, `_Alignof` or `&`.

Comment: @FelixPalmen, I see. That covers all the cases correctly. I will edit the answer to incorporate your wording.

Comment: @FelixPalmen also `offsetof` ?

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya `offsetof` isn't an operator ;) It's a macro, so it doesn't matter here.

Comment: @FelixPalmen, So in case of operators it doesn't decay to `int (*)[3][4]` but in all other cases it will decay to `int (*)[3][4]` right?

Comment: @RajeshR no, not all operators. Only those specific operators mentioned. If you use it as an operand for `+`, it will decay to a pointer.

Comment: @RajeshR the C standard doesn't know the word "decay", but yes, only when used with `sizeof`, `_Alignof` and `&`, it doesn't evaluate as a pointer.

Comment: @RajeshR and if you think about it, it makes a lot of sense. If `sizeof` would just give you the size of a *pointer*, it wouldn't be very useful. Same for the other two operators.

Comment: @FelixPalmen Yeah, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First of all, i did some correction in your program.

1. I have used `int main` instead of `void main`
2. used `%zu` format specifier instead of `%d` because sizeof return `size_t`.

code :

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
   int a[2][3][4];

   printf("%zu",sizeof(*a));  // Output 24.
}
```

Now,  here `a` is a 3D `int` type array of rows 2 and columns 3 and every columns have a 4 elements.

So,

```
 = sizeof(*a) // dereferencing *a 
 = (col * elements) * sizeof(int)
 = (3 * 4) * 4 // sizeof int depend on plat form
 = 12 * 4
 = 48
```

Online [Wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/ymGfMiPl6AAtQOnG) compiler demo.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it will help to think of `a` as

```
[ [ [ int int int int ] [ int int int int ] [ int int int int ] ] [ [ int int int int ] [ int int int int ] [ int int int int ] ] ]
```

and each time you derefference `a` as going inside one set of brackets.

```
   a     2 x 3 x 4 ints
  *a         3 x 4 ints
 **a             4 ints
***a               int
```